# Passing URL parameter to Rest Method through Angular $HTTP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am having trouble sending URL parameters to a rest method through a angular optimized html page.

My rest method:

```
    router.get("/url/id/:urlid",function(req,res){
    var query = "SELECT urlID AS libraryid, "
                + "URL AS libraryitem "
                + "FROM ?? "
                + "WHERE active = 1 "
                + "AND ?? = ? "
    whereClause = ['urls', 'urlid', req.params.urlid];
    query = mysql.format(query,whereClause);
    connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
        if(err) {
            console.log("Rest Call Error");
            res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing MySQL query", "Query" : query});
        } else {
            console.log("Rest Call Success", rows);
            res.json({"Error" : false, "Message" : "Displayed the url  "+req.params.urlid, "Query" : query, "URLs" : rows});
        }
    });
```

I can call the rest method directly and receive the following results

```
{
  "Error": false,
  "Message": "Displayed the url  5",
  "Query": "SELECT urlID AS libraryid, URL AS libraryitem FROM `urls` WHERE active = 1 AND `urlid` = '5' ",
  "URLs": [
    {
      "libraryid": 5,
      "libraryitem": "url"
    }
  ]
}
```

The Controller

```
app.controller("UrlByIDController", function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('/api/url/id/{{urlid}}')
.then(function(data) {
  console.log("URl loading", data)
  $scope.links = data['URLs'];
})
.catch(function(response) {
  console.error('Loading URL error', response.status, response.data);
})
.finally(function() {
  console.log("finally finished loading urls");
});
});
```

The html template

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtURL" class="control-label col-xs-3">URL</label>
    <div class="col-xs-3" ng-controller="UrlByIDController" >
      <input  type="text" 
              id="txtURL" 
              class="ng-valid ng-dirty" 
              ng-model="formData.txtURL" 
              value="{{links.libraryitem}}" 
              placeholder="URL of Ad" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

When I debug the page I don't get an error but the id value that is passed to the rest method is the phrase 'urlid'.  I am sure it is something pretty basic I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access your urlid in your Angular Controller with "{{urlid}}". This syntax can only be used in your HTML Template.

I can't see in your Controller how you get your urlid value from. One possibility would be to access urlid in $scope. But you have to set it somewhere first:

```
$http.get('/api/url/id/' + $scope.urlid)
```

Comment: I am setting the html template in the following code:.when('/ad/create/:urlid', {
            templateUrl: 'AdForm.html'
          })  I will definitely be including the urlid in all circumstances.